# Finding the norm of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have the following operator:

$A: (C^1[0;1];|||\cdot|||)\rightarrow(C^1[0;1];||\cdot||_{\infty})$

$Af(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$

where

$|||f|||= ||f||_\infty+||Af||_\infty$

What is $||A||?$

I wrote

$||Af||_\infty\leq L(||f||_\infty+||Af||_\infty)$

but don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't $A$ map $C[0,1]$ to $C^{1}[0,1]$? Not that it's particularly relevant . . .

Comment: @NickThompson It can do that too, but there is nothing wrong with considering $A$ as a map from $C^1$ to $C^1$. The first copy of $C^1$ has a different norm here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
\left\|Af \right\|_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \left| \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \le \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t  \le \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|\, \mathrm{d}t =: \left\|f\right\|_{L_1} \le \left\|f\right\|_{\infty},
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\left\| A \right\|
&:= \sup_{f \in C^{1}[0,1]} \frac{\left\|Af \right\|_{\infty}  }{\left\|Af \right\|_{\infty}  + \left\|f\right\|_{\infty} } \le \sup_{f \in C^{1}[0,1]} \frac{\left\|Af \right\|_{\infty}  }{\left\|Af \right\|_{\infty}  + \left\|Af\right\|_{\infty} }  \le 1/2.
\end{align}
On the other hand, taking $f =1$ shows that $\left\|A \right\| \ge 1/2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for pointing out that mistake. I'm going to add a correction.

Comment: Can you tell me what function that  $f = \chi_{[0,1]}$ is?

Comment: Sorry, answer is more clear now.